# How to display the image opened using open_image function in fastai?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, fast-ai

How to load the image using fastai open_image function and display the image in a window while executing the python script in command prompt?

I Used img.show() module from fastai to display the image but nothing is displayed while executing the script, though it displays image using this function while running it from spyder IDE.
While using opencv cv2.imshow, it returns this error.
`TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s`

```py
path=pathlib.Path(os.path.normpath('G:/Machine-Deep Learning work/Project/ASL'))
path_image=path/'asl_alphabet_test/B_test.jpg'
img=open_image(path_image)
#img.show(figsize=(10,10),title='Image')
cv2.imshow('Image',img)
```